# Adding play button to trigger javascript time slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, slider

I'm trying to add a 'play' button to a jquery timeslider I have.

Time slider element in HTML:

```
<input id="timeslide" type="range" min="0" max="25" value="0" step="1" /><br>



var inputValue = null;
var years = ["1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009", "2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"];
```

I build an array of years, which will be used to index the time slider based on current slider value.  The data displayed will change based on the year.

```
d3.select("#timeslide").on("input", function() {        
    console.log(value)
    update(+this.value);   
});


function update(value) {

    console.log(value)
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=years[value];
    inputValue = years[value];
    console.log(inputValue)


    d3.selectAll(".tenants")
        .attr("opacity", dateMatch);

}
```

I tried to add 'play' button so that the slider will go through its range of values from start to finish, automatically:

```
    <div class="container">
        <button id="play">
            Start
    </button>

    $('#play').click(function(){    
    $("#timeslide").trigger('input');
    },25);
```

Am I on the right track here?  I just need a button w/ an event listener that will trigger the time slider to scroll through each of its 25 values.

Comment: why not setup an `setInterval()` callback function that loops through the values

Comment: Thanks! Working now.